# Best Method to store sms data in DataBase on OnReceive Method of BroadcastReceiver and then Activities get updated

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have near about six Activities and a service class with BroadcastReceiver that run in background for receiving SMS. I receive SMS on OnReceive Method of BroadcastReceiver now I would like to store incomming sms data in database for that I have made a SMSSync Class for smsProcess which pass data to dbase now I call this smsProcess on OnReceive method this work fine but I think when more sms received at same time the I got found problem I think it was due to database. Sir please tell me what is best method to store sms data after receiving it On receive and then show in activities. Sory for my bad English or if not understand. Thanks in advance sir pl revert back answer I will wait for..I tag code for On Receive method

thanks
Om Parkash Kaushik

public SMSReceiver(Context ctx){

```
    this.context = ctx;
    sync = new SMSSync(context);
    dba = new DataBaseAdapter(ctx);         
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context,final Intent intents){
    if (intents.getAction().equals(ConstantClass.SMS_RECEIVED)) {

        try{
        Bundle bundle = intents.getExtras();            
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            String msg=null;
            String temp = null;
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                msg = message.getMessageBody();
                temp = message.getOriginatingAddress();
            }               
             if(msg.length()>5 && msg.startsWith("<") && msg.contains(">")){

            String len = msg.substring(1, 3);
            int tl = temp.length();
            int l = tl - no;
            address = temp.substring(l,tl);
            int value =Integer.valueOf(len, 16).intValue();
            int index = msg.indexOf(">");
            if(value == index+1){
                dba.Open();                 
                int id = dba.getCordiId(address);
                Cursor cur = dba.getCoord(id);
                if(cur!=null)
                    cur.moveToFirst();
                final String Phnumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DataBaseAdapter.Key_MbNo));
                    if(Phnumber.equals(address)){
                    int count = dba.getDeviceCount(ConstantClass.dbName[1]);
                    if(count<=0){
                        dba.InsertCurrentCoord(id,id);
                    }else{
                        Strsql = new String("UPDATE " + ConstantClass.dbName[1] + " SET " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_ReceiverCoord + " = " + 
                                Integer.toString(id) + " WHERE " + DataBaseAdapter.Key_ID + " = ?");
                        dba.UpdateQuery(Strsql, Integer.toString(1));
                    }
                    dba.Close();

                    sync.smsProcess(msg);

                                            abortBroadcast();
            /************Now deleting the SMS from the Inbox*********************/                  
                                            removeMessage(SMSReceiver.this.context, Phnumber);  
                    if(msg.substring(3, 4).equals("2"))
                        ConstantClass.isAuditrequestSend = false;           

        /*******after receiving the sms opening the Main Screen.*****************/
                    if(ConstantClass.Clear_Main_Screen==true){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,ZigbeeActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(SMSReceiver.this.context, address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(SMSReceiver.this.context, "message Corrupt" + address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        dlg = new ExceptionDialog(SMSReceiver.this.context,"On Sms Receiver" + address ,e.getMessage());
        dlg.show();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the same application related to yours. But instead of saving all received sms i want to save only bank transaction related sms. I hope the following code will helps you..

ReceiveSms.java

```
if(smsg.contains("credit") /***********/ || msg.contains("amount"))
   {
    Toast.makeText(context, "message related to transcation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dbh.smsservice(smsg);
   }
```

DbHandler.java

```
   public void smsservice(String sms) 
        {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String smessg="INSERT INTO SMSDETAILS(SMSMESS) VALUES('"+sms+"') ";
    sdb.execSQL(smessg);
    System.out.println("values of sms inserted"+smessg);
    }
```